# Discord.js: Asynchronous message Cooldown / Antispam

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord Bot that informs Moderators when a user joins a specific voice channel. The Bot is supposed to also have a spam protection that the bot will only log a message once per minute per user.

This is what I have tried before:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const fs = require('fs');


const client = new Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
});

config({
    path: __dirname + "/.env"
})

var supportchannel = '827574015526567947'

var dutychannel = '847445933969113118'

var ondutyrole = '847447374925398016'

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now online!`);
    global.timer = 0;
    client.user.setStatus('online');
    
    client.user.setActivity('me getting developed', { type: "WATCHING"})
        .then(presence => console.log('status set'))
        .catch(console.error); 
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
   
    if(newUserChannel === supportchannel)
    {           
            if (timer == 0){
                timer = 1
                setTimeout(() => {
                    timer = 0
                }, 60000);
                const Userfm = client.users.cache.get(newMember.id);    
                if (Userfm) {
                    const channelfx = client.channels.cache.get(dutychannel)
                    let roleId = ondutyrole
                    channelfx.send(`<@&${roleId}> **${Userfm.tag}** requires Support`);       
                }
            }else{
                return;
            }         
    }
        console.log("User joined vc with id "+newUserChannel)  
});
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

This doesn't work the way intended because the cooldown is not separate for every user but sets a countdown that blocks every user from getting the Moderator's attention for 60 seconds (the users all share a cooldown).

I thought that the code ran asynchronously for every user.

The same goes for this code in which I made use of the wait-sync npm library:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const fs = require('fs');
const waitSync = require('wait-sync');

const client = new Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
});

config({
    path: __dirname + "/.env"
})

var supportchannel = '827574015526567947'

var dutychannel = '847445933969113118'

var ondutyrole = '847447374925398016'

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now online!`);
    global.timer = 0;
    client.user.setStatus('online');
    
    client.user.setActivity('me getting developed', { type: "WATCHING"})
        .then(presence => console.log('status set'))
        .catch(console.error); 
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
   
    if(newUserChannel === supportchannel)
    {           
                const Userfm = client.users.cache.get(newMember.id);    
                if (Userfm) {
                    const channelfx = client.channels.cache.get(dutychannel)
                    let roleId = ondutyrole
                    channelfx.send(`<@&${roleId}> **${Userfm.tag}** requires Support`);
                    waitSync(60);       
                }
                     
    }
        console.log("User joined vc with id "+newUserChannel)  
});
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

If you know how to solve this problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is probably to have some sort of mapping that keeps track of the timer for each user and have the user IDs be the keys:

```
const timers = {};

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
...
    // If we don't have any timer set for this user, go ahead and set it
    if (!timers[newMember.id]) {
        timers[newMember.id] = 1;
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Delete the timer from the mapping
            delete timers[newMember.id];
        }, 60000);
...
```